# How to apply filter component to my products

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, e-commerce, product

Good day,

i would like to apply my filter component to my products. So when the user clicks on the select options, he can choose the size and only the products of the selected size will appear on the screen. I have created the logic, but i just dont know how to apply it.

code FilterAction:

```
const Filterproducts = (products,size) => (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch({
        type:FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE,
        payload: {
            size:size,
            items:size === ''? products: products.filter(a=> a.availableSizes.indexOf(size.toUpperCase())>= 0)
        }
    })
}
```

Code FilterReducer:

```
function producListReducer(state = {products: [], filteredItems: [], size: ''}, action){
    
    switch (action.type){
        // case is like the if statement
        //getting product
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return{loading: true};
            // when products are loaded
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return{loading:false, products: action.payload};
            //when err occurs
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return{loading: false, error: action.payload};
        case FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE:
                return{...state, filteredItems: action.payload.products, size: action.payload.size}
        default:
                return state
    }
}
```

code Filter component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Filterproducts} from '../../actions/productActions'

class Filter extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        
        this.state = {

        }
    }

  
    render(){
        return(
            
            <div className="filter">

                <label>
                    Order:
                    <select>
                        <option value="lowest">Lowest to Highest</option>
                        <option value="highest">Highest to Lowest</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            <label>
            Size:
            <select 
            className="size"
            onChange={(e)=> this.props.Filterproducts(this.props.products, e.target.value)}
            >
            <option value="">ALL</option>
            <option value="XS">XS</option>
            <option value="S">S</option>
            <option value="M">M</option>
            <option value="L">L</option>
            <option value="XL">XL</option>

            </select>
            </label>
          
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    products: state.products.items,
    size: state.products.size
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{Filterproducts})(Filter)
```

Comment: In reducer FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE you need to use filteredItems: action.payload.items as you are sending items not product from action.

Comment: You have to map filteredItems in mapstatetoprops. After that you can use filteredItems.map inside map to show your product.

Comment: @deepak how would you map it in mapstateprops ? It gives a direct error

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Assuming product has name.

```
const Filterproducts = (size) => (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch({
        type:FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE,
        payload: {
            size,
        }
    })
}
```

---

```
 function producListReducer(state = {products: [], filteredItems: [], size: ''}, action){
    
    switch (action.type){
        // case is like the if statement
        //getting product
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return{loading: true};
            // when products are loaded
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return{loading:false, products: action.payload};
            //when err occurs
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return{loading: false, error: action.payload};
        case FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE:
                 const { size } = action.payload
                 const filterProduct = size === ''? state.products: state.products.filter(a=> a.availableSizes.indexOf(size.toUpperCase())>= 0)
                return{...state, filteredItems:[...filterProduct], size: action.payload.size}
        default:
                return state
    }
}
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
                import {connect} from 'react-redux'
                import {Filterproducts} from '../../actions/productActions'
                
                class Filter extends Component {
                    render(){
                        return(
                            
                            <div className="filter">
                
                                <label>
                                    Order:
                                    <select>
                                        <option value="lowest">Lowest to Highest</option>
                                        <option value="highest">Highest to Lowest</option>
                                    </select>
                                </label>
                            <label>
                            Size:
                            <select 
                            className="size"
                            onChange={(e)=> this.props.Filterproducts(e.target.value)}
                            >
                            <option value="">ALL</option>
                            <option value="XS">XS</option>
                            <option value="S">S</option>
                            <option value="M">M</option>
                            <option value="L">L</option>
                            <option value="XL">XL</option>
                
                            </select>
                            </label>
                            { filteredItem.length && filteredItems.map( product => {
                                 return (<> {product.name} </>
                            }
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                }
                
                const mapStateToProps = state => ({
                    filteredItems: state.filteredItems,
                })
                export default connect(mapStateToProps,{Filterproducts})(Filter)
```

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Comment: action payload name is correct as per the given code ?